# How would I open a new window that doesn't focus as it's opened

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to make a custom console where I can log data and errors that happen in my scripts. I'm not sure how to make the window that I open not focus itself when I open it.

This is what I've tried, and it doesn't appear to work.

The reason why I am making a custom console is because my school blocks the inspect tool, and I want to customize how the script outputs information.

I have tried to focus the current window, but it doesn't appear to work.

```js
var ConsoleWindow = window.open('')
ConsoleWindow.blur()
```

I expected the blank window to not focus over the current window I'm running the code in, but it does it anyways and I don't know why.

I'm using a chromebook, so I don't know if that affects how it works.

Comment: You can try `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: You could try using something like codepen.com which has its own console that is not blocked, maybe that will meet your needs. Alternately, make your case to the administration that this should be unblocked on a case-by-case basis, it's ridiculous to expect you to do web development without access to developer tools. Or purchase your own laptop which is free of these draconian managed permissions.